# Xamarin.iOS App crash once on launch - but works on next run

Tags: azure-mobile-engagement

I have a xamarin.ios app developed and decided to connect it to Mobile Engagement. As a result - some of the devices now experience crash on launch. Type of crash is Exception Type:  SIGBUS, Exception Codes: BUS_ADRALN, thread info is useless.. Did any of you encountered this issue? and if so how did you resolve? Crashing line is EngagementAgent.Init(config);

```
Thread 13 Crashed:
0   App                                 0x03fda98c 0xdd000 + 66050444
1   App                                 0x03fdb550 0xdd000 + 66053456
2   App                                 0x03618478 0xdd000 + 55817336
3   App                                 0x036198c8 0xdd000 + 55822536
4   App                                 0x0368051c 0xdd000 + 56243484
5   App                                 0x034813d4 0xdd000 + 54150100
6   App                                 0x0348b198 0xdd000 + 54190488
7   App                                 0x03480afc 0xdd000 + 54147836
8   App                                 0x03680408 0xdd000 + 56243208
9   App                                 0x03680194 0xdd000 + 56242580
10  App                                 0x034906bc 0xdd000 + 54212284
11  App                                 0x0346f470 0xdd000 + 54076528
12  App                                 0x036195e8 0xdd000 + 55821800
13  App                                 0x03618704 0xdd000 + 55817988
14  App                                 0x036198c8 0xdd000 + 55822536
15  App                                 0x0368051c 0xdd000 + 56243484
16  App                                 0x034813d4 0xdd000 + 54150100
17  App                                 0x0348b198 0xdd000 + 54190488
18  App                                 0x03480afc 0xdd000 + 54147836
19  App                                 0x03680408 0xdd000 + 56243208
20  App                                 0x03680194 0xdd000 + 56242580
21  App                                 0x03490978 0xdd000 + 54212984
22  App                                 0x019df0fc 0xdd000 + 26222844
23  App                                 0x034d53f8 0xdd000 + 54494200
24  App                                 0x03511438 0xdd000 + 54740024
25  App                                 0x0348ae58 0xdd000 + 54189656
26  App                                 0x034d27c4 0xdd000 + 54482884
27  App                                 0x019deed4 0xdd000 + 26222292
28  App                                 0x019df0fc 0xdd000 + 26222844
29  App                                 0x034d1dd0 0xdd000 + 54480336
30  App                                 0x019deed4 0xdd000 + 26222292
31  App                                 0x034904ec 0xdd000 + 54211820
32  App                                 0x0346f470 0xdd000 + 54076528
33  App                                 0x036195e8 0xdd000 + 55821800
34  App                                 0x03618704 0xdd000 + 55817988
35  App                                 0x019df0fc 0xdd000 + 26222844
36  App                                 0x03845d88 0xdd000 + 58101128
37  App                                 0x019deed4 0xdd000 + 26222292
38  App                                 0x036bdfac 0xdd000 + 56496044
39  App                                 0x035d766c 0xdd000 + 55551596
40  App                                 0x019df0fc 0xdd000 + 26222844
41  App                                 0x038456a4 0xdd000 + 58099364
42  App                                 0x019deed4 0xdd000 + 26222292
43  App                                 0x019df0fc 0xdd000 + 26222844
44  App                                 0x03845444 0xdd000 + 58098756
45  App                                 0x039c8b40 0xdd000 + 59685696
46  App                                 0x04006610 0xdd000 + 66229776
47  App                                 0x034813d4 0xdd000 + 54150100
48  App                                 0x03b1f458 0xdd000 + 61088856
49  App                                 0x016dbd10 0xdd000 + 23063824
50  App                                 0x016db414 0xdd000 + 23061524
51  App                                 0x016dbca0 0xdd000 + 23063712
52  App                                 0x016f2c94 0xdd000 + 23157908
53  App                                 0x016f2a70 0xdd000 + 23157360
54  App                                 0x016dbbe4 0xdd000 + 23063524
55  App                                 0x016db9f0 0xdd000 + 23063024
56  App                                 0x016db848 0xdd000 + 23062600
57  App                                 0x016fc594 0xdd000 + 23197076
58  App                                 0x008ad3ec 0xdd000 + 8193004
59  App                                 0x016fe0c8 0xdd000 + 23204040
60  App                                 0x0198d198 0xdd000 + 25887128
61  App                                 0x0026c087 0xdd000 + 1634439
62  App                                 0x002c9805 0xdd000 + 2017285
63  App                                 0x002ea1c1 0xdd000 + 2150849
64  App                                 0x002f0daf 0xdd000 + 2178479
65  App                                 0x00332b6f 0xdd000 + 2448239
66  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x1b515a27 _pthread_body + 217
67  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x1b51594d _pthread_start + 235
68  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x1b51349c thread_start + 8
```